# How to run malloDroid script?

Tags: android, python, androguard

I want to check SSL verification in my application. I downloaded on my santoku malloDroid.py and try use it (of course earlier I have read that script is an extansion of Androguard). I simply run mallo app: `./malloroid.py -f test.apk` and i got import error that there is no androguard module. How to run malloDroid script to verify ssl?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use MalloDroid, you need to have AndroGuard. Setting up Androguard is quite straight forward. Read more about installation [here](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/wiki/Installation) .

Once you have Androguard set up along with the proper environment variables, you can use Mallodroid as follows :

```
./mallodroid.py -f test.apk -x
```

This will most likely work!